# Scripting language that cannot interact with the Outside world

Tags: interpreter

I need a way of flexible defining the order certain tasks are performed. There is no parallelism, only one task is active at a time. Every task has an outcome (a set of primitive values, like Integers Floating points or Strings. Which task is performed next can depend on the outcome of previous tasks.

Most of the time these dependencies are simple, like "outcome > 5". But sometimes they are more complex. For example a certain task is performed next, if a certain word occurs multiple times in the String-output of a previous task. They can also be more complex conditions in ways I do not think of yet.

So my Idea is to use a simple scripting language to define the flow/order of tasks. Than it can look like this:

```
outcome1 = performTask('task1');
outcome2 = performTask('task2');
if (outcame1.value > 3 && outcome2.value == "success) {
    performTask('task3');
} else {
    performTask('task4');
}
```

I like the Idea. Now the questions raises which scripting language to use?

Since the end user will write the scripts and possibly exchange scripts with other users, I am worried about "viruses". The outcome data is highly confidential so there must not be a way to somehow output the data. Ideally I would limit the usage of the language to the core functionality (assuming this does not involve any IO) plus a set of functions I provide.

At first I will use the language in a C++ project, but it would be nice if the browser (javascript) could be supported in the future.

I could invent my own scripting language and write my own interpreter, but that would be much work I am hoping to avoid.

So which scripting language with which interpreter could I use to meet this requirements?

Comment: It seems maybe you are asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188798/choosing-embedded-scripting-language-for-c

Comment: Well, they suggest lua. Can lua be limited in the way i need it? I googled around but die not find out how to do that ...

Comment: You want the users to be able to write their own scripts but the scripting language they use to be incapable of writing output? That seems like you need to create your own scripting syntax & custom interpreter. However, if you have control over the invocation of the process which executes the scripts you can control write permissions that way. Run the process in a restricted way for your OS. That would be simpler than inventing a scripting language which allows no output.

Comment: An example of tackling your "no output" problem from an OS-perspective instead of a programming-perspective: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/securing-restricted-shell-environments

Comment: That is an very interesting Idea, but I am developing for several platforms and it seems to me that such an os oriented approach means a lot of work in this case. I looked around and it seems one can start lua without loading the io library. Maybe that is the answer, but I am not sure if this would really close all possibilities.

Comment: "...start lua without loading the io library." Sounds good enough to be an answer. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What one usually does for this is "sandboxing" For example lua can be sandboxed, which is described [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes).